# Windows C++ How to install GLFW library?

Tags: c++

I am coding window part of my game. Code gives error. I think the reason of the error is the lack of `GLFW` library. I am using `Notepad++` for editing and `MinGW` for compiling. How can I install a library to my folder?

Error:

```
NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\User\Desktop\game\src\main.cpp
CD: C:\Users\User\Desktop\game\src
Current directory: C:\Users\User\Desktop\game\src
g++ "main.cpp" -o main -march=native -O3
Process started (PID=1568) >>>
In file included from main.cpp:4:
Display.h:7:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<<< Process finished (PID=1568). (Exit code 1)
NPP_RUN: main
; executing: NPP_RUN main
- the specified file was not found
================ READY ================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't install a library, you just need to tell the compiler where to find the headers and libraries you require. How you do this depends on your build environment.
If you use only mingw g++ you need the following options:

- `-I` (that's an uppercase i!)(specify path to include files, in your case the path to glfw/include directory)
- `-L` (path to libraries, in your case to the folder that contains glfw3.lib)
- `-l` (that's a lower case L!)(a list of libraries to use, in your case glfw3, without the extension)

Comment: Do I need to add `GLFW` library's zip file to `C:\MinGW\include`?

Comment: No, why would you? You need to extract it first. Wherever you like. Then just tell your compiler where to find those files.

Comment: I extracted the files to my program's `Dependencies` folder. I typed `g++ -l C:\Users\User\Desktop\game\Dependencies` and it gave error. Error: `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\User\Desktop\game\Dependencies`

Comment: `-l` adds a libary by name, as I said. It should be `-lglfw3`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But my program's exe gives this error: `Program too big to fit in memory`. How can I solve this? I am new to C++

Comment: Better ask a new question for this one ;)